# increasing the log level of shiny server on ubuntu 16

Tags: shiny

I am running shiny server (open source) on Ubuntu 16.04. In order to debug, I want the log level to be increased from INFO to TRACE.
I followed these instructions [here](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#server-log) which is:

**Step 1**
Adding a line in file: /etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service under the `Service` section

> Environment="SHINY_LOG_LEVEL=TRACE"

**Step #2:** Then I restarted the shiny server by executing:

`$ sudo systemctl stop shiny-server
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
$ sudo systemctl start shiny-server`

But the logging is still identical to the previous logging. Do the logs come in some other file apart from here (in Ubuntu 16.04)?

```
rstudio@ip-172-31-30-19:/var/log/shiny-server$ ls -lt |grep "shiny"
-rw-r----- 1 rstudio rstudio  572 Jun 16 18:51 shinymf-rstudio-20180616-185145-41642.log
-rw-r----- 1 rstudio rstudio  572 Jun 16 18:47 shinymf-rstudio-20180616-184723-38798.log
-rw-r----- 1 rstudio rstudio  572 Jun 16 18:38 shinymf-rstudio-20180616-183756-40440.log
-rw-r----- 1 rstudio rstudio  572 Jun 16 18:36 shinymf-rstudio-20180616-183645-42780.log
-rw-r----- 1 rstudio rstudio  572 Jun 16 18:33 shinymf-rstudio-20180616-183332-46571.log
-rw-r----- 1 rstudio rstudio  731 Jun 16 18:30 shinymf-rstudio-20180616-183020-39225.log
-rw-r----- 1 rstudio rstudio  560 Jun 16 18:26 shinymf-rstudio-20180616-182630-34886.log
```

All my log files contain the same content despite I making lot of changes:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:38798
Plotting
Calling RM
Warning: Error in plot.nsdl: object 'CAS' not found
  47: plot.nsdl
  44: <observer> [/home/rstudio/nsdl/shinymf/app.R#32]
   1: runApp
```

I have checked many times and not clear how the `object 'CAS' not found` error is coming.

The same shiny app runs fine from rstudio `runApp()` call.
But when the shiny app is accessed through public IP address from a browser the app starts and immediately closes.

Any help in debugging the problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with shiny server installed in CentOS Linux 7 (core). Got any workaround?

Comment: This is a little dated problem so I don't really remember what I did eventually to work around this. So apologies for being forgetful.

Comment: I also found a sort of workaround: instead of `cat` I'm using `message` to print relevant info in the server logs.